# Hope I didn't forget / I haven't forgotten anything

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Why is the difference between:

(I know there is another topic about, but they say that I have to use PP if there is a relevance in the present but in both cases there is a relevance?)

> I hope I didn't forget anything

> I hope I haven't forgotten anything

To me, I have to use the PS if I forgot something and I cannot come back to take it.
The PP if I forgot something and I can come back home to take it.

Am I right?

Comment: If I was on my way to my destination after packing the car, I would say "I hope I haven't forgotten anything." If I later discover that something is missing, I would say "I forgot to bring X."